# Failing to copy data from a file to an array of structs (c)

Tags: arrays, c, file, struct, scanf

for starters, I'm sorry for any errors that I might have made, but english isnt my mother tongue. I'm also sleep deprived and anxiety ridden, because Ive waited to the last minute possible to ask for help.
i have a problem and at this point I'm not even sure what it is, but I think it's either my fscanf or my malloc.
I have an array of structs and I need to copy the information in the file in the structs of this array.
I will add more data in the file when I manage to successfully copy the data of the first struct.
I can't change the structs, because they were given like that to me for an assignment.

I really tried to do this on my own, but I haven't slept in 2 days and I can't for the life of me find out what Im doing incorrectly. At this point, Ive stared at the code so much, that the error could be in front of me and I still woudnt manage to see it. Any advice is welcome!!!

This is what my catalog.txt looks like

[image]

This is what my videoclub.h looks like

```
#define SIZE 100
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct date{
    int day, month, year;
}date;

typedef struct director_info{
    char *director_name, *director_surname;
}director_info;

typedef struct movie{
    int id;
    char *title;
    director_info *director;
    date *release_date;
}movie;
int loadArray( movie *array, FILE *fp);
```

This is what my main.c looks like

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "videoclub.h"

int main()
{   

    movie *array;
    FILE* fp;
    int logs;
    

    fp = fopen("catalog.txt", "r");
    if( fp == NULL) printf("Could not open file catalog!\n");


    logs = loadArray(array, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    printf("%d\n", logs);
}
```

this is my code in videoclub.c

```
int loadArray(movie *array, FILE *fp){

    char c;
    int counter, logs, i;

    counter = 0;
    i = 0;

    for (c = getc(fp); c!= EOF; c = getc(fp)){                           //counts how many lines our file has
        if (c == '\n')
            counter = counter + 1;
    }
    logs = counter/7;                                                    //how many logs of movies do we have?

    array = (movie*) malloc (logs * sizeof(movie));                     // allocating memory for array


        array[0].title = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char) * SIZE);
        array[0].director = (director_info*) malloc (sizeof(director_info));
        array[0].director->director_name = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char) * SIZE);
        array[0].director->director_surname = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char) * SIZE);
        array[0].release_date = (date*) malloc (sizeof(date));
        
        
        i = fscanf(fp, "%d\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%d\n%d\n%d\n ", &(array[0].id), array[0].title, array[0].director->director_name, array[0].director->director_surname, &array[0].release_date->day, &array[0].release_date->month, &array[0].release_date->year);
        printf("%d\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%d\n%d\n%d\n", array[0].id, array[0].title,  array[0].director->director_name, array[0].director->director_surname, array[0].release_date->day,array[0].release_date->month, array[0].release_date->year );
        printf("%d\n", i);
        printf("test\n");
        
        return logs;
    


}
```

This is what I get:
[image]

Comment: Please post text as text, not images of text.

Comment: Im sorry. I tried to write it as text but it just wouldn't change lines. Thank you for the advice, ill look into it! @ScottHunter

Comment: You need to rewind.  You read through `fp` just to get a line count.  But if you don't rewind the file there is no more data to read so your scanfs have no data to work with.

Comment: Note that rewinding the file is *not* the correct solution, but it is probably the fastest route forward for you.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I cannot thank you enough. Seriously, if I could, Id bake you a basket of cookies. I'll use the rewind to finish my assignment, as I have v little time left, but out of curiosity, what would be the correct solution? (please answer only if you have time and energy, your answer has already helped me enough)

Comment: In general, you never want to scan a file just to count the number of entries.  Instead, the "correct" approach is to read the file and reallocate space as needed to accommodate all the data.  By scanning the data and rewinding, you make it impossible to implement the process on a stream (non-regular file).

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thank you very much!!!